Flutter Background and Terminated Tasks
I want to achieve the execution of he flutter code in the background and terminated state. This is what I exactly want ->
When the Firebase push notification arrives I want to call an API that will send an acknowledgment to thee server that the receiver has got the notification.
I have tried the onBackgroundHandler it runs in the background and terminated state but it fails to hit the API.
I have tried work manager package. It doesn't work properly I have even tried the example they provided but id doesn't work in the terminated state.

The flutter service does not run when the app is terminated. So, calling an API in that state does not work.
In your case, to know whether the app got the notification, you can rely on the Firebase response while sending push notifications to the device.

yes I've got the solution we can do it in the on Background method of Firebase. We just need to hit the API without any await .
